# Migrating Standalone named instance to AlwaysON

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

Scenario:
I have a named instance such as SERVER1\NAME.

I need to migrate this instance to an AlwaysON, but I'd like to use the same instance name in the listener. Is it possible?

I was planning a side-by-side migration:

- Create 2 new instances. (SERVER2\NAME and SERVER3\NAME)
- Create a Listener called SERVER1_NEW.
- Once everything is ready for the cut-over, just rename the SERVER1 to SERVER1_old and then rename SERVER1_NEW to SERVER1.

Is that going to work? 
The plan is to avoid changing the connection strings everywhere.

Comment: We're missing quite a big piece of the information: What's the connection string data source look like now?

Comment: @SeanGallardy, the application is connecting directly to SERVER1\NAME. 
I'd like to use the same name (listener) to avoid changing the connection string everywhere. Is that possible?

Comment: So the answer given is then incorrect because listeners don't work with the browser service, so continuing to use a named instance as such will not work. You'll most likely need to add in a sql alias if you want that functionality without changing the connection string.

Comment: Hey @SeanGallardy, just to let you know, I was able to connect to the listener using instance name (Listener\Name). I'm not sure if that was the solution, but I changed the port number in both instances (SERVER2\NAME and SERVER3\NAME) to 1433. 
After connecting setting up the Listener, I tested it using Listerner\Name and it worked just fine.

Comment: Bege, you didn't actually use the instance name - the only reason it works is because it's on 1433. The browser service DID NOT respond to an interrogation. If you want to test it out, change the port to anything but 1433 and the connection will fail. Again, the "solution" is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its very much possible and I completely concur with your idea as starting with new server and do all the required and once all set-up, get a short window of down-time. Take database backup and restore it on the new server. Once sanity and basic testing is completed successfully, switch off the old server or rename it with some other name and allocate that name to new server.

- Create 2 new instances. (SERVER2\NAME and SERVER3\NAME)
- Create a Listener called SERVER1_NEW.
- Once everything is really for the cut-over, just rename the SERVER1
  to SERVER1_old and then rename SERVER1_NEW to SERVER1.

You may read wonderful article on how to do set up of windows always on availability group by Priyanka Devre as below:

https://www.sqlshack.com/configuring-a-sql-server-alwayson-high-availability-group/

Hope above helps.